# Django ManytoMany field remains empty after .add() method called

Tags: python, django, django-models, manytomanyfield

I'm using django to create a signup platform where students can signup to weekly classes.
Each class is a django model called `ClassCards` which has a ManytoMany relation to `User` model called `signed_up_student` that represents all the users signed up for that class as seen below

```py
class ClassCards(models.Model):
    content = models.CharField(max_length=100, default = '')
    date = models.DateField(blank=True, null = True)
    time = models.TimeField(blank=True,null=True)
    signed_up_students = models.ManyToManyField(User,blank=True)
    full = models.BooleanField(default = False)
    max_students = models.IntegerField(default=4)
    teacher = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='Adi')
```

I would like to add a subscription option that will automatically sign up subscribed students to this weeks class. Here is my `Subscription` model:

```py
class Subscriptions(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null =True)
    day = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=day_choices, null=True)
    time = models.TimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    num_of_times_used = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    cap = models.IntegerField(default=52)
    active = models.BooleanField(default= True)
    expirey_date = models.DateField()
    date_created = models.DateField(default = timezone.now)
```

To accomplish this I have created a `post_save` signal:

```py
@receiver(post_save,sender=ClassCards)
def apply_subsciptions(sender,instance,created, **kwargs):

    if created:
        subs = Subscriptions.objects.filter(day=instance.date.strftime("%A"), 
time=instance.time)

        for s in subs:
            instance.signed_up_students.add(s.user)
            print(instance.signed_up_students.get())
```

The code runs properly when a `ClassCards` is saved without throwing any errors and the print statement prints the relevant `User` However when I look on the admin page, I see that there are no users in the `signed_up_students` field.
I Would like to understand why this isn't working as desired which should adding that user to the `ManytoMany` field and what is the best practice for automatically updated a `ManytoMany` fields.

Answer (score 0):

a little modification to the class ClassCards

```
 class ClassCards(models.Model):
         signed_up_students = models.ManyToManyField(User, symmetrical=False, related_name="student_cards_students_has", blank=True)


   def signed_students_list(self):
    return self.signed_up_students.all()

   def cards_asigned_to_student_list(self):
    return self.student_cards_students_has.all()

   def assign_student(self, user):
    self.signed_up_students.add(user)

   def unsign_user(self, user):
    self.signed_up_students.remove(user)
```

now in the signals

```
@receiver(post_save,sender=ClassCards)
def apply_subsciptions(sender,instance,created, **kwargs):

    if created:
        subs = Subscriptions.objects.filter(day=instance.date.strftime("%A"),time=instance.time)

        for s in subs:
           instance.assign_student(s.user)
           instance.save()
        print(instance.signed_students_list())
        print(instance.cards_asigned_to_student_list())
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. so im assuming that you meant - instance.assign_student(s.user). that is without the .add() as .add is being used in the function itself

Comment: However this is still not working. meaning i am not seeing the user that has the subscription in the ClassCard manytomany field on the admin page. The most frustrating thing is that the print statement actually prints that user but he does not exist on the admin page

Comment: about the .add() sorry i eddied it i missed that 
about the admin page don't know what about if you made queries in views do you get the added user to course?

Comment: When i query inside the apply_subscription function i get the user but when i query any where else i get an empty set and also i dont see him in the ui on the admin page

Comment: Mmmm maybe we could add the save method even in common cases just doing .add() works to save data to manytomany fields 
but why not go and try the my_obj.save() after using add

Comment: that was actually my first goto solution but it did not work